# How can I change my child's iCloud account to a 'regular' Adult account?

Tags: icloud

My son is now over 18 and I wish to change his Apple iCloud account
to the regular 'Adult' account. I see numerous questions the other way
around (adult->to->child), but that's not want I need answered.

Comment: does this help? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201081

Comment: It is something related to 'Ask to Buy' ...

Answer (score 1):

Aha! I found it - on iPad -> Settings -> iCloud -> Family -> Ask to Buy